# Menu hover issue

Tags: css

With the CSS  below, I'm trying to get the hover effect to ommit the current page but it doesn't.

```
#access li:hover  a,
#access ul ul :hover a{
    background: #37617a;
}



#access ul li.current-menu-item  a:hover {
    background:none
}
```

Comment: Those 3 selectors are entirely different.  If you bring them more inline it should be easier to spot any differences in specificity.  What structure are you looking to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want, taking #access as the id of the ul.  [jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/KYFQg/)

```
#access li:hover a{
    background: #37617a; }

#access li.current-menu-item a{
    background:none }
```